# Find and replace string in a list of filenames

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, unix

I have a couple of files like so, (on Mac OS X):

```
product-103-footer.tpl
product-103-header.tpl
product-103.tpl
```

I want to replace '103' in all the filenames with something else using grep and sed, or something like that.

How do I do it?

Here's some pseudo command line of what I want to achieve

```
find . /[103] | grep 103 | sed s/103/104/
```

Hope this makes sense!

EDIT:

Getting closer:

```
find . -name 'product-103*' -print | sed 's/103/104/g'
```

Comment: I can replace a string using sed: echo 'product-103' | sed 's/103/104/g', but need to loop each file and rename them individually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `find`'s `exec` option to (recursively) loop over all files, then use simple string replacements:

```
find . -type f -name "product-103*" \
-exec sh -c 'echo mv "$0" "${0/103/104}"' '{}' \;
```

Remove the `echo` when you're sure this does what you want.

Basically, what `exec` does is substitute the file name of every file found in `{}`, which is passed as an argument to `sh -c`. This argument is available as `$0`, thus the file name. We use this `$0` argument in a `mv` call, where the second argument is the new file name. Here, 103 is replaced with 104. Note that double quotes are needed to correctly handle whitespace in the file names.

See [String Manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) in the Bash Scripting Guide.

---

With zsh's `zmv` (on OS X through `/bin/zsh`):

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv -Wn '*103*' '*104*'
```

Remove the `-n` option when this does what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Perl is better for this.

```
find . -name 'product-103*' | perl -nle '($new=$_) =~ s/103/104/;rename $_,$new'
```

The following piece of code

```
perl -nle '($new=$_) =~ s/103/104/;rename $_,$new'
```

will eventually be expanded to

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    ($new=$_) =~ s/103/104/;
    rename $_, $new;
}
```

The `<>` operator will get each file name with an '\n' at the end and save it to $_, then `chomp` will chop the '\n' off. Then variable `$new` gets the old filename from `$_` and replace 103 to 104. At last, `rename` just rename the file in question to its new name.
For more details about the -n -l -e switch, refer to the [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) part of perldoc.

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in product-103*; do mv "$f" "${f/103/104}"; done
```